# Recurrence relation with complex roots

Tags: recurrence-relations

$$a_n=4a_{n-1}+5a_{n-2},\quad  a_1=2,a_2=6$$

$$x^2-4x-5=0$$
$$x=-2+i,-2-i$$(complex roots)
as per the quadratic equation for the roots, $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Then what is the formula ?

thank for confirming the roots just need one more clarification, after substituting these roots my a_n=C_1(-1)^n+C_2(5)^n
=>a_1=C_1(-1)^1+C_2(5)^1
=>a_1=-C_1+5C_2
similarly for
a_2=C_1(-1)^2+C_2(5)^2
=>a_2=C_1+25C_2
If this solution correct.

Comment: What formula do you need? I mean, the reccurence formula is $a_n=4a_{n-1} + 5a_{n-2}$.

Comment: The solution of your quadratic equation is wrong. $x=-1$ is an obvious root and $x=5$ is the second root. $b^2-4a c=16+20=36$. I suppose you missed a sign.

Comment: Actually, even with complex roots, you just use the formula for the general solution you have been using.  However, as Claude Leibovici mentions, your discriminant is 16+20, so your roots are real.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that the roots you gave in your post are wrong, the solution to your problem is fully described in the link  lab bhattacharjee provided in his comment.

So, learn (if still required) the method and apply it. You should arrive to $$a(n)=\frac{2}{15} \left(2\ 5^n-5 (-1)^n\right)$$